# Draw a rectangle wherever mouse is clicked on panel and change its color

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a rectangle on a panel wherever the mouse is clicked. When the user clicks the same rectangle again, it will change its color. It has to be drawn on a panel.

What I have done with the help of the internet is this. It displays a message mouse is clicked between the coordinates of the rectangle drawn first.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int xcord1;
    public int ycord1;

    Dictionary<Color, List<Rectangle>> rectangles 
        = new Dictionary<Color,List<Rectangle>>();

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {              
            //Gets a color for the rectangle
            Color c = Color.Blue;

            //Adds the rectangle using the color as the key for the dictionary

            if (!rectangles.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                rectangles.Add(c, new List<Rectangle>());
            }
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 && textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = e.Location.X.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = e.Location.Y.ToString();
                xcord1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                ycord1 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            }
            if (Cursor.Position.X <= xcord1 + 100 && Cursor.Position.X >= xcord1 
                && Cursor.Position.Y <= ycord1 + 100 && Cursor.Position.Y >= ycord1)
            {    
                MessageBox.Show("click");                   
            }
            else
            {
                rectangles[c].Add(new Rectangle(e.Location.X - 12, e.Location.Y - 12,100,100));
                //Adds the rectangle to the collection
            }
        }       
        //Make the panel repaint itself.
        panel1.Refresh();          
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //The key value for the dictionary is the color to use to paint with, so loop through all the keys (colors)
        foreach (var rectKey in rectangles.Keys)
        {
            //Create the pen used to draw the rectangle (using statement makes sure the pen is disposed)
            using (var pen = new Pen(rectKey))     
            {
                //Draws all rectangles for the current color
                //Note that we're using the Graphics object that is passed into the event handler.
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(pen, rectangles[rectKey].ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}









}
```

Comment: I kind of do not understand the purpose of your code. You are making rectangles. All you want is to change color of rectangle when user clicks on it again. Now, you are allowing overlapping rectangles. So, which should be re-painted?

Comment: @danish the one that is drawn on first click must be re-painted when user clicks on it again

Comment: Yes but what if rectangles overlap?

Comment: they can overlap  ,the only thing that i want is how can i change the color of rectangle that is drawn on first click when it is clicked again

Comment: This smells like homework.